# Update InputStream before further processing

Tags: java, spring, inputstream

I've got a system where I process files basing on a sample file. So basically I should receive excel file with headers and then rows with information. Now the users send some additional headers and trailers which fails in processing in Apache POI.

I've added additional fields on GUI where user can add how many leading and trailing rows are additionally so I can remove them while parsing excel. So basically I receive a file as an InputStream on spring endpoint then the validation happens and then file is pushed to S3. So I am wondering if there is any chance to update that InputStream and remove that wrong records before S3 upload?

Do I need to save updated file and then read it back to get new InputStream or there is any better way to do that?

```
    public InputStream cleanFileBeforeS3Upload(InputStream inputStream, Definition definition) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        var workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
        var sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        ExcelUtils.removeLeadingAndTrailingRowsFromExcel(sheet, definition.getTrimLeadingRows(), definition.getTrimTrailingRows());

        // ????? How to get new updated inputstream from above workbook
        return inputStream;
    }


//Line which upload file to S3
var request = new PutObjectRequest(s3Properties.getBucket(), s3ObjectKey, file.getInputStream(), metadata);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like:

```java
...
var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(out);
return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```